# Use just Month and Year in date strings, to find which combination is older

Tags: ruby, date

I have a requirement to compare two date strings, and to find which is older month. there is no day parameter in both strings. Is there any pre build method available in Ruby or in any of its library?
Eg: 1) December, 2015
    2) August, 2013 
     Find which date is older?

Comment: Converting to a `Date` object is easiest, but another way would be to create a hash `h = { 'January'=>0,...''December'=>11 }` and compare with `[year,h[month]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can use the 'Date' library with the parse method like so:

```
require 'date'
=> true
date1 = Date.parse('December, 2015')
date2 = Date.parse('August, 2013')
date1 > date2
=> true
date2 > date1
=> false
```

Comment: There is no advantage using DateTime. Date would work as well without dragging around the time values.

Answer (score 1):

Same as Anthony's answer, using `time`

```
require 'time'
a = "December, 2015"
b = "August, 2013"
t1 = Time.parse(a)
# => 2015-12-01 00:00:00 +0530
t2 = Time.parse(b)
# => 2013-08-01 00:00:00 +0530
t1 > t2
# => true
```